# Display IP & TCP statistics per interface (netstat -s with interface)

Tags: linux, tcp, netstat

Linux has the ability to display protocol statistics with netstat -s. The output looks something like:

Excerpt:

```
7487 times unabled to send RST due to no memory
TCPDSACKIgnoredOld: 817
TCPDSACKIgnoredNoUndo: 7246527
TCPSpuriousRTOs: 4583587
TCPSackShifted: 15825
TCPSackMerged: 455582
```

But these are accumulated over all networking interfaces. Is there a way to see these statistics per interface? I know that there are packet level statistics in `/sys/class/net/$INTERFACE/statistics`, but have not been able to find any protocol related ones.

Answer (score 1):

Netstat -s is a more intuitive display of `/proc/net/netstat`. Counters in it are global and not per interface. To get that kind of information you will need to use/write a monitoring tool using libpcap.

Comment: I am aware of it. But as that file isn't necessarily the full extent of statistics that are being kept, I was hoping for something else.
Libpcap has too great of an overhead/will not keep up with the data rate, so that solution is out.

Answer (score 0):

The code which captures these statistics is called in the various related TCP/UDP/IP codepaths and increments SNMP MIBs.

There is no information stored about interface or any connection properties like port or IP, it's only a basic counter of the times that codepath has been entered.

`netstat -s` just reads those counters.